# How can I point headless wordpress admin panel links to proper urls without using frameworks?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, htaccess, headless

I have a headless wordpress website. The frontend, built using React, without headless WP frameworks, is in the public_html directory. The wordpress backend is in the public_html/back directory. Accordingly, all admin panel links point to site-domain/back/resource, whereas I want links such as view draft/view post to point to site-domain/resource. I've tried the [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory) guide, but that resulted in Invalid JSON Response Error. Would redirecting all urls that do not have /wp-admin in them, using .htacess placed in the wordpress folder, work?

Comment: I don't see why redirects wouldn't work, and it should be super easy to test. Previews may be problematic though but that's better asked as a separate question